# Search output for time and summarize it

Tags: regex, bash, grep

The final goal is to setup an website with dynamic statistics.
For that I already created an mysql database and count the total amount of known players on our minecraft server.
**Next step is to show the playtime of all players altogether.**

I have an "activetime.conf" where the playtime for all players is listed.

**activetime.conf:**

```
config {
    auto-save=300
    default-range=5
    max-range=10
}
players {
    "111-111-1111-11-11" {
        name=playerjack
        time="2h13m25s"
    }
    222-2-22222-2-222 {
        name=playergert
        time="14m13s"
    }
}
```

**What I already have:**

```
players=$(ls -l /path | grep -v ^d | grep -v ^t | wc -l)
mysql -u root -pmypass mydatabase -e "UPDATE mytable SET players = '$players';"
hours_played=$(grep -E '"*h*m*s"' /path/activetime.conf)
echo $hours_played
```

We have the following string "hours_played" and like to search it for time information + summarize the times to finally show the full hours only.

**hours_played:**

```
time="2h13m25s" time="14m13s"
```

**Final result should be:**

```
2
```

**Why the result is 2 ?**

```
2h13m25s + 14m13s = 2h27m38s (=2h)
```

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: Can you share few more examples?

Comment: I edited my question to show what's the goal and what I have.

Comment: show the final desired output

Comment: The final needed result is shown below. Just "2" for "2 hours".

Comment: try looking at the plain output of `grep -E '"*h*m*s"' /path/activetime.conf` . Then think about what you have to do to clean it up. Add that code to above like `| sed '....'` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is use a function to parse the time info (hours, mins, seconds):

```
#!/bin/bash

active_time() {

    regex='time.*\"(.+)h(.+)m(.+)s\"'

    while read -r str; do
    if [[ $str =~ $regex ]] ; then
        h=$(( h + BASH_REMATCH[1] ))
        m=$(( m + BASH_REMATCH[2] ))
        s=$(( s + BASH_REMATCH[3] ))
    fi
    sub=$(( m / 60  ))
    tot=$(( h + sub ))
    done<"/path/active_time.conf"
    echo "${tot} total hours"
}
```

So instead of echoing the last last line `echo $hours_played` you would just call:

```
active_time
```

Calling the function totals up the hours and minutes, so for example:

```
time="8h13m25s"
time="6h54m13s"
```

Would output:

```
15 total hours
```

<sub>*Summing the seconds and adding to the total has been omitted as an exercise for the OP to add if desired.</sub>

Comment: U did it! Thx alot :) I'll try to add the secs to the total when the time comes for it.

Comment: One thing to note, if you can possibly put "0h" for times that are only minutes/seconds it will work much better. For example (0h25m35s)... otherwise the minutes and seconds get ignored until they show an hour value.